# Kapt generatestubs - Cannot initialize object with internal constructor from unit-test

Tags: unit-testing, constructor, kotlin, dagger-2

Let say we have a kotlin class defined as:

```
package foo

class Bar internal constructor() {
//...
}
```

When I try to init that object from a test method like:

```
package foo


class TestBar {
    @Test
    fun testingBar() {
        Bar()  //<----- error
    }
}
```

I get a following error:

```
Cannot access '<init>': it is internal in 'Bar'
```

Both Bar and TestBar are in the same AndroidStudio module (android library)
Both paths to sources were defined in a gradle:

```
...
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
}
...
```

Tests seem to work fine in general, but I'm unable to create any object with a internal constructor.

I'm using:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
```

---

### EDIT

Thanks for the feedback.
I've decided to make simple android multi-module application from scratch and it worked just fine.

Then I tried to get rid of my module dependencies one by one and it turns out that problem is caused by dagger2 gradle dependency.

```
dependencies {
    ...

    //dagger 2
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
}
```

When I remove the dependency I am able to access internal constructor from tests without a problem.
Is that an indication of a bug or my dependency is not defined properly?

---

### EDIT 2 (Solution)

It turns out that problem was caused by kapt's `generatestubs = true` option.
In order to make tests see internal classes just switch to a new kapt implementation:

http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html

which in my case came down to getting rid of

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

and adding

`apply plugin: kotlin-kapt'`

at the beginning of gradle file.

Comment: where your 2 classes live?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683991/kotlin-make-an-internal-function-visible-for-unit-tests

Comment: Project stucture is like:

`-root/module/src/main/kotlin/foo/Bar
-root/module/src/test/kotlin/foo/TestBar`

Comment: Hi, could you check the thinest example on github. due to there is no android environment in  my machine .

Answer (score 2):

`internal` visibility means that the class is visible only in the same module. [Kotlin's definition of a module is](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules):

> More specifically, a module is a set of Kotlin files compiled together:
>
> - an IntelliJ IDEA module;
> - a Maven project;
> - a Gradle source set;
> - a set of files compiled with one invocation of the Ant task.

As far as I know you `main` and `test` are 2 separate source sets and that's the reason why it's not working.

```
main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
```