# Kotlin internal members not accessible from alternative test source set in Gradle

Tags: testing, gradle, kotlin, integration-testing, visibility

Following https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests and https://www.michael-bull.com/blog/2016/06/04/separating-integration-and-unit-tests-with-gradle we are attempting to separate our integration tests from plain unit tests.

The problem we have is `internal` members in Kotlin are not accessible from such tests. As per [Kotlin doco](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules) there is a visibility exception for test source sets.

> The internal visibility modifier means that the member is visible
>   within the same module. More specifically, a module is a set of Kotlin
>   files compiled together:
>
> 1. an IntelliJ IDEA module;
> 2. a Maven project;
> 3. a Gradle source set (with the exception that the test source set can access the internal declarations of main);
> 4. a set of files compiled with one invocation of the  Ant task.

Is there a way around it other than not trying to access them? That would call for a major refactoring of hundreds of tests and potentialy the whole codebase.

Comment: This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60346360/484293) discusses some failed attempts. Did you happen to find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get a custom test sourceSet to access `internal` classes by adding the following code to my custom Gradle plugin.

```
NamedDomainObjectContainer<KotlinWithJavaCompilation<KotlinJvmOptions>> compilations = project
  .getExtensions()
  .getByType(KotlinJvmProjectExtension.class)
  .target.getCompilations();

compilations.getByName(sourceSet.getName())
  .associateWith(compilations.getByName(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME));
```

I looked at the `kotlin-gradle-plugin` source code and found the following:
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.3.61/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinPlugin.kt#L488-L490

With change, the tests in my custom source set run just fine, but IntellIJ still shows compilation errors. I'll look further to see if I can make IntelliJ happy as well

Comment: That's a useful pointer but I cannot manage to translate this into anything in the Groovy DSL (though I am trying with MPP in the mix too): `kotlin { ... targets.jvm.compilations.test.associateWith targets.jvm.compilations.main }`. Seems `associateWith` is not exposed for users.

Comment: In MPP I think you need to add a dependency on `compileMain` kotlin source set. There are several references to the `compileMain` and `compileTest` sources sets. For example, https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ece7a3e70e7c04cb2f599512284ed840e00936c6/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/metadata/KotlinMetadataTargetConfigurator.kt#L51-L57

Comment: This answer talks about making IDEA happy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35690003/2740621