# Tests in Gradle sub-project cannot see Kotlin internal visibility

Tags: gradle, kotlin, jmh

[Kotlin `internal` visibility](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) is scoped to the "module" including the helpful statement that it may be:

> a Gradle source set (with the exception that the test source set can access the internal declarations of main)

... so you can unit-test internal methods.

My Gradle build holds performance tests in a sub-project. How can I make those also "see" internal items of the parent?

The standard import doesn't do this

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':myParentName')`
}
```

If it's impossible from a sub-project, how can a custom source-set (i.e. not `test`) in the main project have the same exception?

PS. It is quite common to see JMH performance tests put into a sub-project to keep configuration from polluting from the main `build.gradle`. This doesnt mean they are only tests of public interfaces (see the `M` in JMH).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050889/kotlin-internal-members-not-accessible-from-alternative-test-source-set-in-gradl?

Comment: 57050889 is specifically for a custom sourceSet. I don't think that will help here either because of a validation check that appears to force `associateWith` to be quite localised. https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/45ab07654eaecab82236133fa33135632f142534/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/mpp/kotlinCompilations.kt#L205