# How to make Kotlin `internal` objects accessible to tests?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, source-sets

My project uses several Gradle source sets for its production code base instead of just `main`:

- `domain`
- `dal`
- `rest`
- `test`
- `dbUnitTest`

This has proven very useful for limiting dependencies and enforcing separation of concern.

It comes with one downside however: we cannot access classes or methods with [visibility `internal`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) from within test classes. The reason for this is that the Kotlin compiler places every source set in its own "module":

```
$ find . -name '*.kotlin_module'
./classes/kotlin/domain/META-INF/contact-management_domain.kotlin_module
./classes/kotlin/dal/META-INF/contact-management_dal.kotlin_module
./classes/kotlin/rest/META-INF/contact-management_dal.kotlin_module
./classes/kotlin/test/META-INF/contact-management.kotlin_module
./classes/kotlin/dbUnitTest/META-INF/contact-management_dbUnitTest.kotlin_module
```

I would like all sourceset to use the same module name "contact-management", as the main sourceset would by default.

I tried to override the name with the compiler option [`-module-name`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-reference.html):

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        // place all source sets in the same kotlin module, making objects with 'internal' visibility available to every source sets of this project
        freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-module-name \"contact-management\")
    }
}
```

Upon running `gradlew build`, I get

```
> Task :contact-management:compileDomainKotlin FAILED
e: Invalid argument: -module-name "contact-management"
```

The reason being that `-module-name "contact-management_domain"` is set before by the Gradle code invoking the Kotlin compiler as well, but apparently this option is only accepted once.

**In a Gradle build, how can I control what is being considered ["one module"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules) by the Kotlin compiler?**

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57050889/484293) where the `test` source set is to be split has no satisfactory answers so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using kotlin *compilation*s. (As far as I understand, a *compilation* is simply a block of files that are compiled together. A good explanation can be found [here](https://medium.com/xebia-france/understanding-the-basics-of-multiplatform-projects-in-kotlin-1-3-1221689b3084))

When you create a sourceset in gradle, the kotlin plugin creates a *compilation* under the hood (with the same name as the sourceset).

What you can do now with compilations is create associations. If a compilation *A* is associated with another compilation *B*, source code in *A* gets access to internal code units of *B*.

So in your case, if the *test* sourceset should get access to the *dal* sourceset you can simply associate the *test* compilation with the *dal* compilation:

```
kotlin.target.compilations.getByName("test").associateWith(kotlin.target.compilations.getByName("dal"))
```

PS: It also works the other way around. If you create *compilations* explicitly, the corresponding sourcesets are created under the hood. So for custom sourcesets you can create compilations and associate them:

```
val domainCompilation = kotlin.target.compilations.create("domain")

val dalCompilation = kotlin.target.compilations.create("dal") {
    associateWith(domainCompilation)
}
```

In above example, the sourceset *domain* will have access to internal code units of the sourceset *dal*.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that by now, the concept of `compilations` has been [documented pretty well](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-configure-compilations.html#compilation-of-the-source-set-hierarchy), it's just hidden in the 'multiplatform' chapter...