# gradle test suite different filters for same test source set

Tags: gradle

I try to setup a gradle `integrationTest` test suite using `jvm-test-suite` for my kotlin & spring-boot project. I want to only have a single source set for all test suites (i.e. src/test) and each suite shall filter which tests it actually runs.

This is my attempt:

```
@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
testing {
  suites {
    configureEach {
      if (this is JvmTestSuite) {
        useJUnitJupiter()
        dependencies {
          implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
          implementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
          implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
          implementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.5")
          implementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:4.0.0")
          implementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
          implementation("org.testcontainers:r2dbc")
          implementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
        }
        targets {
          all {
            testTask.configure {
              /* See https://mockk.io/doc/md/jdk16-access-exceptions.html
                 "Note: this includes creating @SpyKBean on spring data repository instances,
                 because they are instances of java.lang.reflect.Proxy in fact."
                 "Add JVM argument --add-opens java.base/full.package.name=ALL-UNNAMED for each
                 package you need to mock. Package name should be fully qualified." */
              jvmArgs = listOf("--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) {
      useJUnitJupiter()

      targets {
        all {
          testTask.configure {
            minHeapSize = "512m"
            maxHeapSize = "2048m"
            finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport)
            filter {
              excludeTestsMatching("*Integration*Test")
              excludeTestsMatching("*.integration.*")
              excludeTestsMatching("*Repository*Test")
              excludeTestsMatching("*Controller*Test")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    register<JvmTestSuite>("integrationTest") {
      useJUnitJupiter()
      sources {
        java {
          setSrcDirs(test.sources.java.srcDirs)
        }
        kotlin {
          setSrcDirs(test.sources.kotlin.srcDirs)
        }
        resources {
          setSrcDirs(test.sources.resources.srcDirs)
        }
        compileClasspath += test.sources.compileClasspath + project.sourceSets["main"].compileClasspath
        runtimeClasspath += test.sources.runtimeClasspath + project.sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
      }
      dependencies {
        implementation(project)
      }

      targets {
        all {
          testTask.configure {
            shouldRunAfter(test)
            filter {
              includeTestsMatching("*IntegrationTest")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when running `./gradlew testIntegration` I get a compile errors that complain about usage of `internal` classes:

```
e: file:///some/path/src/test/kotlin/my/company/somepackage/SomeTest.kt:145:62 Cannot access 'SomeClassB': it is internal in 'SomeClassA'
```

This is how my class definition lookgs alike

```
@Component
class SomeClassA(
 val transactionManager: ReactiveTransactionManager,
) {
  internal data class SomeClassB(
    val foo: Int,
  )
 // ...
}
```

I am currently still on gradle 7.4.2 and `./gradlew test` does what I want it to do (run all tests but the excluded ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59260030/386201) answer I got the idea of adding the following to the `sources` configuration which makes it work:

```
    val compilations = project
      .extensions
      .getByType(KotlinJvmProjectExtension::class.java).target.compilations
    compilations.getByName(sources.name)
      .associateWith(compilations.getByName(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME))
```

So the full config looks like:

```
register<JvmTestSuite>("integrationTest") {
  useJUnitJupiter()
  sources {
    java {
      setSrcDirs(test.sources.java.srcDirs)
    }
    kotlin {
      setSrcDirs(test.sources.kotlin.srcDirs)
    }
    resources {
      setSrcDirs(test.sources.resources.srcDirs)
    }
    compileClasspath += test.sources.compileClasspath + project.sourceSets["main"].compileClasspath
    runtimeClasspath += test.sources.runtimeClasspath + project.sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath

    // make internal classes available to tests
    val compilations = project
      .extensions
      .getByType(KotlinJvmProjectExtension::class.java).target.compilations
    compilations.getByName(sources.name)
      .associateWith(compilations.getByName(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME))
  }
  dependencies {
    implementation(project)
  }

  targets {
    all {
      testTask.configure {
        filter {
          includeTestsMatching("*IntegrationTest")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```