# How to test kotlin function declared `internal` from within tests when java-test-fixtures module is in use

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, kotlin, java-test-fixtures, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I've tried to make use of [test fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures) in my project in kotlin. Unfortunately I have encountered a strange problem, probably a bug, in a component of the toolchain (not sure which one).

Normally a Kotlin function in `main` declared `internal` can be accessible from a unit `test` from the same package. There's a number of proofs supporting this claim, particularly [Kotlin: Make an internal function visible for unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683991/kotlin-make-an-internal-function-visible-for-unit-tests)

Indeed if we have [src/main/kotlin/ main.kt](https://github.com/amorozov/broken-test-fixtures/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main.kt):

```
@file:JvmName("Main")
package org.example.broken_test_fixtures

internal fun sayHello(who: String): String = "Hello, $who!"

fun main() {
    println(sayHello("world"))
}
```

and [src/test/kotlin/SayHelloTest.kt](https://github.com/amorozov/broken-test-fixtures/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/SayHelloTest.kt):

```
package org.example.broken_test_fixtures

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class SayHelloTest {
    @Test
    fun testSayHello() {
        val expected = "Hello, world!"
        val actual = sayHello("world")
        assertEquals(actual, expected)
    }
}
```

the test is passed successfully with a regular [build.gradle.kts](https://github.com/amorozov/broken-test-fixtures/blob/5b29b0129b35a4338cc355d6d2faddaf9dee082c/build.gradle.kts):

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
}


group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

So far so good.

But with [an addition](https://github.com/amorozov/broken-test-fixtures/blob/master/build.gradle.kts) of a single line into the plugins list:

```
id("java-test-fixtures")
```

the build of the test gets broken with the following error:

```
e: /home/work/users/alex/broken-test-fixtures/src/test/kotlin/SayHelloTest.kt: (10, 22): Cannot access 'sayHello': it is internal in 'org.example.broken_test_fixtures'
```

I've discovered that similar problems were mentioned in [Gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11094), [Kotlin Gradle plugin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20760) bug trackers. Unfortunately I couldn't extract a solution from those issues. Perhaps, it's a different problem.

For the reader's convenience I have prepared a tiny [repo on Github](https://github.com/amorozov/broken-test-fixtures) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since Kotlin 1.3.60 there's an `associateWith` Gradle Kotlin Plugin API implemented in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20760

From 1.9.20 it'll be by default enabled for test fixtures too, as mentioned in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34901

For now <1.9.20, this project has all kinds of references:
https://github.com/TWiStErRob/repros/tree/main/kotlin/test-fixtures-and-suites-friends

It might show errors in IDEA, but it works in command line. Errors each line fixes are commented in `build.gradle.kts`, pick the one you need :)